# Ocamlbuild copy over dependencies to _build

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild

I'm trying to use ocamlbuild to automatically invoke [piqi](http://piqi.org/) to generate ocaml modules from protobuf definitions. This is a 2 step process where I have to go from a `%.protobuf` file to a `%.proto.piqi` and finally to `%_piqi.ml`.

My rule for the first step looks as follows:

```
rule "piqi: .proto -> .piqi"
  ~dep:"%.proto"
  ~prod:"%.proto.piqi"
  begin fun env build ->
    Cmd (S [ A piqi ; A "of-proto"
           ; A "-I"; P protobuf_include
           ; P (env "%.proto") ]
        )
  end;
```

But this doesn't work because the `%.proto.piqi` target is actually dependent on all the "*.proto" files in my source directory because the individual `.proto` files import each other in the source. However, I'm not sure how to express this dependency between them in ocamlbuild. It would be enough if all of the proto files where copied over to `_build` rather than just the one in `~dep`

Answer (score 1):

Calling `build` on a file from inside a rule action will register it as a dynamic dependency of the target. You can just loop over all `*.proto` files that you know may be accessed by the current one (either globbing the source directory or, more cleverly if that gives any benefit, parsing the include statements) and `build` them.

(Another way to think of this solution is to remark that, if you wanted to have some `foo.proto` file generated by some preprocessing step from a `foo.proto.pp`, then you would need any compilation needing `foo.proto` to actually call `build` on it.)

See the [dynamic dependencies](https://github.com/gasche/manual-ocamlbuild/blob/master/manual.md#rules-dynamic-deps) section of the new manual draft.

P.S.: I don't know anything about protobuf but from `protoc --help` it looks like `protoc --include-imports --descriptor_set_out FILE` may give you the list of a `.proto` dependencies in some format. Parse that and call `build` on all of them, and you've got a nice and robust rule.